# Finding the set of wildcards for representing a binary interval

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, wildcard, trie, switching

In a switch flow table there is a field called match field, where a list of matching condition is maintained. In the match fields, binary sequences with wildcards (*, a bit of wildcard character means that it could be either 1 or 0 in this bit) are used to represent some matching conditions.
For example, we can use the following binary sequences with wildcards to represent the matching condition '38798 <= Port <= 56637':

```
100101111000111*
100101111**1****
100101111*1*****
1001011111******
10011***********
101*************
110111010011110*
1101110100***0**
1101110100**0***
1101110100*0****
11011101000*****
11011100********
110**0**********
110*0***********
1100************
```

Does anyone know (or suggests) a way to obtain such sequence? So far, I used a brute force strategy (getting all the possible combinations for the intervals), but it is not computationally feasible (memory explosion) and has a problem of redundancy (wildcards representing the same interval). So now I'm trying to use *range splitting* and *grid-of-tries* to get a solution, but without success yet.